# Is there a way to share S.M.A.R.T. data over SNMP?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp, cacti, smart

Is there a way to share S.M.A.R.T. data over SNMP? I'd like to be able to make cacti graphs of it and hook it up to Nagios.

What I want to do is be able to get some statistics on my harddisks accessible over SNMP. This will allow me to graph the number of $SMART_MEASUREMENT_VALUE against time.

Comment: You need to elaborate a lot more if you want a decent answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will suit your needs: Quoted from this [link](http://en.doc.centreon.com/HowToUseSNMPAgentExtension):

You'll need the SmartMonTools package and use *check_smart.pl* perl script (nagios plugin) to check hard drive health by running S.M.A.R.T. self-tests using the smartctl command, add to your snmpd.conf:

> exec CheckSmart
>   /path/to/check_smart.pl -t -d /dev/hda

Comment: It is interesting to see SMART parameters changing in time. And this plugin only tests current value.

Comment: @exquisitor: SNMP commonly only supplies the current value; it is usually the task of the management server collecting the data to store old data for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

There are patches that add SNMP support to smartd (in smartmontools-devel@ list); none were integrated, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell answer is right, but is missing the download a url for the script:

http://git.recluse.de/?p=users/bzed/nagios-plugins.git;a=blob_plain;f=plugins/check_smart

i also add this line below on line 109 of the script, to avoid a warning

```
if (!defined($number)) { $number = 0; }
```

For those without nagios, the script requires a util.pm lib. Debian users can get it from 
nagios-plugins package and other users can grab it from here:

https://github.com/Elbandi/nagios-plugins/blob/master/plugins-scripts/utils.pm.in

the usage is simple:

```
./check_smart.pl  -i scsi  -d /dev/sda
```

but i agree with exquisitor comment, a way to graph all (or at least some important) smart values would be great

**UPDATE**: the script DO output other smart values, but only if you choose the ata interface (-i ata). As today all drivers (even ata/sata) are seem as scsi devices, this create confusion (and its probably a bug)
So i recommend for those with ata/sata drivers to edit the script and on line 209 replace the check from "ata" to "scsi"